# Xcode - Multiple photo filters

Tags: ios, xcode, filter, photo, core-image

I'm creating a photo app that involves filters. The filters work, but they stay permanent and overlap each other. I want, for example, the sepia filter to be removed from the image and replaced with the instant filter when the instant filter button is pressed. How do I achieve this? Here is some code from the project:

```
- (IBAction)sepiaFilter:(id)sender {

    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.picture.image)];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil ];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cging = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    self.picture.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cging];
    CGImageRelease(cging);     
}

- (IBAction)instantFilter:(id)sender {

    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.picture.image)];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIFilter *filterTwo = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil ];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filterTwo outputImage];
    CGImageRef cging = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    self.picture.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cging];
    CGImageRelease(cging);
}
```

(I actually have nine filters, but I just need an idea on how to do this) Thanks for any help

Comment: Keep your original image, when user apply a filter then decided to use another one, just put your original image back instead of try removing filter.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple. You are using `self.picture.image` for input as well as output. Keep an original `UIImage` separately for input, and use `self.picture.image` only for output, so the only thing in your code changes is the first line of both the filters ie

```
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.originalImage)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but the image disappears. Any idea why this is happening?